# How do I know if my RAM slot or CPU socket is gone bad

Tags: boot, memory, cpu, motherboard, ramdisk

So I recently had some issues with my system booting.

At first, It would end up in a boot loops. No beeps, nothing, just fans start spinning for a second, then go off for a second only to start again. I tried removing part after part and nothing fixed it.

I then did a CMOS reset and things changed. After the CMOS reset, the fans would start spinning, however, neither did the monitor get any signal, nor did the keyboard or mouse power up.

I tried removing components one by one again to find the culprit. Again nothing. I then did yet another CMOS reset and then switched the RAM slot. I have only 1 4 GB stick and 2 RAM slots. Changing the slot fixed the problem.

Just to be sure, I tried interchanging the slots 3-4 times, everytime I had the same results. (System boots with slot 2 and not on 1). However, it was essential for me to do a CMOS every time I swapped the slots. Without a CMOS reset both slots showed the same results (spinning fans and nothing else).

Initially, I concluded that the RAM slot was the culprit. However, I read [here](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/bad-ram-slot-on-motherboard.2842862/) and [here](https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/problems-in-ram-slot-1/) that "memory management is also handled by the CPU" and that there could be an issue with the CPU or CPU socket too. I'm not very experienced when it comes to removing/placing the CPU on the Mobo. Would prefer not to touch it and avoid further damage.

I am now confused. Below are my questions

1. How do I determine where the problem really is. As of now I do not need if I need a new CPU, Motherboard or none (proceed and use slot 2)
2. Is it safe to temporarily use the system with the stick in slot 2? It seems to boot and function completely normally.

[EDIT] It was working fine, all this started when I purchased a computer table, the whole story is [here](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/blank-screen-no-power-to-keyboard-and-mouse-on-boot.3472601/)

Comment: In two cases, bad RAM slot, bad CPU slot, the solution is to change moterherboard, so why bother finding out ? You cannot without specialized equipement. So you have two, faulty mb or faulty CPU. To find out if it is the CPU, test with another CPU. I have also seen that a BIOS update does this, to test this, place a seond DIMM in the first RAM slot.

Comment: I actually do not have a spare CPU, and am not very experienced with handling CPU placement on the MoBo. Given that the RAM works fine on slot 2, could I assume it's a sound one and hence if it does not work on slot 1, then it's not a BIOS issue

Comment: What you describe indicates the socket itself is bad not the CPU. The socket would communicate with the memory, a bent pin would interfere with the communication between the CPU and the memory. By only using certain modules you are avoiding that pin (in theory).  However, if it was working on Day A, and overnight it stopped working, its unlikely a bent pin.

Comment: It was working fine, all this started when I purchased a computer table, the whole story is [here](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/blank-screen-no-power-to-keyboard-and-mouse-on-boot.3472601/)